# SVG image not showing (many ways tried)

Tags: html, svg

This is my code:

```
<svg class="navbar-brand" src="/Images/logo.svg" alt="Apps Architect"></svg>
```

I have tried changing svg to img or embed. With img image is not rendering but alternate text is showing. With embed image is not showing, alternate text neither. So I have changed:

> xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,

to:

> xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,

I've added div 
`<div><img class="navbar-brand" src="/Images/logo.svg" alt="Apps Architect"></div>`

I've change `xlink:href` instead of `src`.

Then I've tried to use:

```
<image ... xlink:href="...">
```

But it doesn't change anything.

EDIT: I've added width and height but it doesn't change anything. But it shows properly after compiling in Visual Studio. Only on the server it doesn't showing.
I've added png file instead svg and it doesn't showing neither.

Comment: @xmastertje u mean svg file?

Comment: no your folder structure. My bad used a dutch word

Comment: Is your SVG anyway valid? Are you able to preview it in the developer tools? `<svg>` and `<image>` is actually not valid HTML but XML in SVG (open your svg image with a text editor and check the XML inside it). To display a SVG image in browser you have to use the "normal" `<img src="bla.svg"/>` image element.

Comment: @xmastertje svg file is in the Images folder and html file is in the main folder. Main/Images

Comment: Add your folder structure. Also see if you are referring to actual path.

Comment: @RajmondX it shows properly after compiling in Visual Studio on the webpage. But only on the server it doesn't show.

Comment: Are you sure your `src` is good? /If i have to guess your path is like this `../Images/logo.svg`

Comment: @xmastertje src="/Images/logo.svg"

Comment: @P.M. Please show us your folder structure

Comment: Do you have a SVG file ? or only have svg code

Comment: @xmastertje There is sth with folder structure. I've added png file instead svg and it doesn't showing neither. This is my folder structure on server /public_html/www.appsarchitect.pl/index.html. and this is my svg path /public_html/www.appsarchitect.pl/Images/logo.svg

Comment: @P.M. show me a picture please

Comment: And try this `<svg class="navbar-brand" src="../Images/logo.svg" alt="Apps Architect"></svg>`

Comment: @xmastertje THANK YOU for your path attention.

Comment: @P.M. No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution in my path there was `"/Images/logo.svg"` and it should be `"Images/logo.svg"`